# Haskell - Function signatures

Tags: haskell

I am having difficulties understanding the issues with implementing certain functions. I have a general data type defined as follow :

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
data Stuff x = Stuff (Map.Map x [x])
```

When I try to implement a function such as this :

```
foo :: Ord x => x -> x -> Stuff x -> Stuff x
foo a b (Stuff c) = Stuff (Map.insert (a b c))
```

I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Map.Map x [x]’
            with actual type ‘a0 -> Map.Map k0 a0 -> Map.Map k0 a0’
```

However, when I verify the signature in the Haskell docs:

> insert :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a

If it's returning a "Map k a", can't type "a" be a list? How could I turn "a" into "[a]"?

Comment: Terminology note: `[a]` is the type of lists, not of arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(a b c)` applies function `a` to arguments `b` and `c`, when it looks like you want to provide `a` `b` and `c` as arguments to `Map.insert`. You can't provide `b` directly since it has the wrong type (`x` instead of `[x]`) but you can create a singleton list to insert:

```
foo :: Ord x => x -> x -> Stuff x -> Stuff x
foo a b (Stuff c) = Stuff (Map.insert a [b] c)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the other mistake with regards to the parameters! It works!